# nullity of a convex combination of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

I have the following question.
Given two matrices of the same dimension $A, B\in \mathcal R ^{m\times n}$ , and consider a third one given by a convex combination of them
$$
C = c_1 A + c_2 B
$$
$c_1 + c_2 = 1$, and  $c_i \le 1, \quad i \in \{1,2\} $

what could one say about the dimension of the kernel of this last matrix? 
My opinion is that, almost for all combinations, the kernel has the same dimension. There are nevertheless "some" combination that could make the dimension increase.

I mean, these singular cases are nowhere dense respect to the convex combination.

Is such a statement true?

Answer (score 0):

In general, we really can't say anything about the nullspace of a sum of matrices consider $A=-B$ and $c_1=c_2=\frac{1}{2}$ then nullspace of $C$ is whole space or for $A=B=I$ and $c_1=c_2=\frac{1}{2}$, then$\ker C$ is trivial.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly my point. 
Take $A=-B$ as you suggested. Then it results $\ker(c_1 A - c_2 A)= \ker((c_1- c_2)A)$. That is the result is almost always $\ker A$ except for
$c_1=c_2=1/2$ by which the nullity increases.

So my conjecture is for general $A$ and $B$, could one say that the nullity increases only for singular choices of $c_1, c_2$?